# 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' is not recognized

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer, google-vision

When I tape `npm init start` on visual studio code for working with google cloud platform, the terminal gives me this error :

```
'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Translation: "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Google Cloud Library, which relies on authentication.

**Quote** from the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application):

> GCP client libraries use a strategy called Application Default Credentials (ADC) to find your application's credentials. When your code uses a client library, the strategy checks for your credentials in the following order:
>
> 1. First, ADC checks to see if the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set. If the variable is set, ADC uses the service account file that the variable points to. The next section describes how to set the environment variable.
> 2. If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Cloud Functions provide, for applications that run on those services.
> 3. If ADC can't use either of the above credentials, an error occurs.

You need to create a service account and create a credentials file when using the service. After that, you set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to its path. See the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) for more information.